# Importing csv file in Cassandra Database throws error Record #0 (line 1) has the wrong number of fields 1 instead of 7

Tags: csv, cassandra, cqlsh

AM using the copy method for copying the CSV file into the Cassandra tables.. But am getting records error of has wrong number of fields .

Query is ---COPY activity FROM 'Detail.csv' with HEADER=TRUE

i have my activity as column family with 7 fields
but in my csv file everything is separated by semicolon

Error is Record #0 (line 1) has the wrong number of Fields (1 instead of 7)
Above image is Screen Shot of CSV file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in my csv file everything is separated by semicolon

The default behavior of the [COPY](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/copy_r.html) command uses a comma as a delimiter.  Since your file is (apparently) semi-colon-delimited, it will see the entire row as one field (unless the data contains commas).  Try setting the `DELIMITER` option in your `WITH` clause.

```
COPY activity FROM 'Detail.csv' WITH HEADER=TRUE AND DELIMITER=';';
```

And as a suggestion, I have always had more luck getting `COPY` to work properly when listing-out the columns to import:

```
COPY airplanes (name, manufacturer, year, mach) FROM 'temp.csv';
```